# Ionic Framework - show / open iCloud directly

Tags: ionic-framework

I am developing a ionic(v1) app, in the app i need an functionality to upload pdf files from iCloud drive. I have added the iCloud capabilities and it works fine.

So what issue i facing now is, when I click on the upload button I want to show just iCloud option only like in whatsapp 'share document' link. 
Is there any way to hide the rest of the options in the upload?

[I have attached a simulator screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xokFi.png)

and my sample code

```
<form name="form">
<div class="button" ngf-select ng-model="picFile" name="picFile">Select</div>
<button ng-click="uploadPic(picFile)">Submit</button>
</form>

$scope.uploadPic = function(file) {
    console.log(file);      
    file.upload = Upload.upload({
      url: dataUrl,
      data: {file: file},
    });
}
```

Thanks to all